# Removing a portion of a list of strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a list of 400+ strings and I need to remove three characters at the end of every line.

```
rank_f = np.genfromtxt('Ranked Features.dat', delimiter='.',dtype=str)
rank_f = rank_f[:,np.array([False, True, False,])]
```

The resulting array is:

```
array([[' Seismic: amplitude_2000-3000_chan26 MA (0'],
   [' Seismic: iq75_25_3000-4000_chan11 MA (0'],
   [' Seismic: iq75_25_2000-3000_chan19 MA (0'],
   [' Seismic: iq75_25_2000-3000_chan10 MA (0'],
   [' Seismic: RMS_3000-4000_chan20 MA (0'],
   [' Seismic: amplitude_10-200_chan23 MA (0'],
```

How can I remove the space + ( and 0 from every single one of them?
IE the first row become 'Seismic: iq75_25_3000-4000_chan11 MA' and not: 'space ...(0'

mapping gets rid of the entire row, replace doesn't work, and I don't know if I am using the methods incorrectly or if my data type is the wrong kind of this specific method.

The idea is to use other code + functions to read every element and it only accepts a string 'S....MA'

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solutions.

```
rank_f = [[i[0][:-3]] for i in rank_f]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked wonders. Didn't think of this

Comment: @user16276856 if this solves your issue,please mark as accepted answer,happy coding!!!